# Lost WiFi connection after Windows 7 - intel driver Centrino Wireless N1000 Update - How do I restore the driver?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers

I was updating my computer; hp Pavilion dm4, Windows 7, 64-bit operating system. I got an error stating "Intel driver update for Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless N1000" could not be updated. I tried to investigate further under the Device Manager, Network adapters, Intel WiFi Link 1000 BGN, it displays the device status: "This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31)"

I've tried installing an update from Intel's website, this didn't work. I tried restoring my system prior to the update, this didn't work. Can anyone suggest anything else? I hope I don't have to reformat my computer to its original manufacturing status.

Comment: What software did you use to "update" the dm4?

Comment: had the same problem with my dm4 also....restored to my last setting and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Search for *Device Manager* in start menu, open it, find your device.Right click on the device and select prperties, select the **Driver** tab
[image]
Click rollback driver, if possible.
If you can't roll back, I would recomment you to update your driver from that window and see what happens.
<strike>If none works, do a system restore, I hope Windows has created a restore point before installing updates, so look for the most recent restore point and do it</strike>.
Another option is uninstalling the driver and reinstalling with an older one.

Note:If you don't want to try restore, **wait for other answers**.

Comment: They said they did a restore and it did not work.

Comment: @Moab Oh, sorry. I didn't read the last part.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar just happen, found this while researching, and figured I'd share my fix.  Went into device manager, right clicked on the broken network adapter, then selected update driver software.  Here, instead of searching online, I clicked on browse my computer.  On the next screen, I selected let me pick from a list of devices.  There, I selected the Intel WiFi Link 1000 BGN option and clicked next and everything was back to normal. Hope that helps.

Comment: I"m guessing moving forward....I will not be updating anything re: Intel WiFi